# css3 menu with inverse rounded corners

Tags: html, css, menu, css-shapes, rounded-corners

I designed a navigation menu which looks like the image here:

[image: inverse rounded corners]

I want to code it with css3 rounded corners and box-shadows, not using any images.
Problem is the rounded corner to the left of the first menu-item, and the one to the right of the menu... I call it a "reverse" rounded corner...

It should have to change color on `:hover`.

Is there any way to get this done in css only? And how?

Comment: Have a look at this for the general idea: http://css-tricks.com/tabs-with-round-out-borders/

Answer (score 5):

### HTML

```
<div class="menu">
    <div class="outer_bg_left">
        <div class="outer">
            <div class="outer_shadow">
            </div>
        </div>   
    </div>

    <ul>
        <li class="menu_item_cont"><div class="menu_item">Item 1</div></li>
        <li class="menu_item_cont"><div class="menu_item">Item 2</div></li>
        <li class="menu_item_cont"><div class="menu_item">Item 3</div></li>
    </ul>

    <div class="outer_bg_right">
        <div class="outer">
            <div class="outer_shadow">
            </div>
        </div>   
    </div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
.outer_bg_left, .outer_bg_right {
    float: left;
    width: 70px;
    background-color: #994;
    height: 15px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10;
}

.outer_bg_left .outer {
    height: 25px;
    border-radius:  0 10px 0 0;
    background-color: #fff;
}

.outer_bg_right .outer {
    height: 25px;
    border-radius:  10px 0 0 0;
    background-color: #fff;
}

.outer_bg_left .outer_shadow, .outer_bg_right .outer_shadow {
    box-shadow:  0 0 5px 2px rgba(0,0,0, .7) inset;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    margin-bottom: -10px;
    height: 25px;
}

.outer_bg_left .outer_shadow {
    border-radius: 0 10px 0 0;
    padding-left: 30px;
    margin-left: -30px;
}

.outer_bg_right .outer_shadow {
    border-radius:  10px 0px 0 0;
    padding-right: 30px;
    margin-right: -30px;
}

.menu_item_cont {
    background-color: #994;
    border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px 2px rgba(0,0,0, .7);
    background-color: #994;
    display: block;
    float: left;
}

.menu_item {   
    border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
    background-color: #994;
    height: 20px;
    padding: 5px 10px;

    font-family: Arial;
    line-height: 20px;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.menu_item:hover {
    background-color: #000;
    border-radius: 10px;
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    color: #fff;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gXQzU/4/

It's just my first attempt, but I think it looks quite promising.

Comment: Please bring your CSS in-line with your answer. Otherwise those that might find your answer useful are at the mercy of JS Fiddle.

Comment: Hey that's great @ogur! Only the hover state should contain the inverse rounded corner in black :s

Comment: I know, but it may need using scripts. Also area with inverse rounded corner is not transparent, but white.