# achieve this tabbed effect in css

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am creating some tabs for my website, and I am trying to match the design, which used some very uneven lines, which is obviously tricky to pull off in css.  Here is a sample:

[image: tabs]

Right now I am using bootstrap tabs to achieve the actual functionality of the tabs.  Here is my start

http://jsfiddle.net/PJbhQ/2/

```
.nav-tabs > li > a{

   box-shadow: -2px -1px 3px -1px #aeaeae, 2px -1px 3px -1px #aeaeae;
   background-image:linear-gradient(to bottom, #fefefe, #dddedd);
  border-bottom: none;
}
.nav-tabs > li.active > a {
   box-shadow: -2px -1px 3px -1px #aeaeae, 2px -1px 3px -1px #aeaeae;
   color: @gray;
   background: #ffffff;
   border-bottom: none;
 }
```

Any ideas on how to get this curvature?

Comment: You probably need a border or a background image for the right part

Comment: yeah perhaps just for the curvature.  Im thinking it may be possible with a :before and :after css effect though?

Comment: I would add a right border and some padding. You can some content with :after, but I don't see how will that help.

Comment: what you're asking for is not easy. [Here's a tutorial to get you started with round-out tab borders](http://css-tricks.com/better-tabs-with-round-out-borders/), but the sloped edges will be very tricky to achieve with pure CSS. You may find it impossible; it may be better to switch to using SVG for this.

Comment: http://www.css3.info/preview/rounded-border/ look at example D

Comment: Example D is definitely not enough. I started a try http://jsfiddle.net/wMC7F/ and it appears one of the biggest problem will be to set an outset background on the `li:after` (in my example)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok here's my very crude attempt at this using pure CSS..

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/PJbhQ/4/

Here's the CSS:

```
.nav-tabs > li > a{

    box-shadow: -2px -1px 3px -1px #aeaeae, 2px -1px 3px -1px #aeaeae;
    background-image:linear-gradient(to bottom, #fefefe, #dddedd);
    //border-bottom-color: transparent;
    border-radius: 8px 20px 0 0;
    border-bottom: none;
}
.nav-tabs > li > a:after{
    background-attachment: scroll;
    background-clip: border-box;
    background-color: transparent;
    background-image: radial-gradient(circle at 100% 0 , rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 14px, #999 17px, #dddedd 18px);
    background-origin: padding-box;
    background-position: left bottom, right bottom, right top, left top;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    content: "null";
    color:rgba(0,0,0,0);
    height: 20px;
    left: 31px;
    position: relative;
    top: 8px;
    width: 20px;
    z-index: 5;
}

.nav-tabs > li.active > a {
    box-shadow: -2px -1px 3px -1px #aeaeae, 2px -1px 3px -1px #aeaeae;
    color: @gray;
    background: #ffffff;
    border-bottom: none;
}   
.nav-tabs > li.active > a:after{
    background-attachment: scroll;
    background-clip: border-box;
    background-color: transparent;
    background-image: radial-gradient(circle at 100% 0 , rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 14px, #999 17px, #fff 18px);
    background-origin: padding-box;
    background-position: left bottom, right bottom, right top, left top;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

(HTML and JS are the same)

I used gradients for the convex curve as seen from [Inset border-radius with CSS3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11033615/inset-border-radius-with-css3)

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: I actually convinced my client that this was just a bad idea in the first place, but your example is very close to being what I asked for, kudos for doing it in CSS only!  I hope this serves as a good example for others later on