# CSS: How to round box corners inside?

Tags: css

There're `border-radius` property to round box corners. But how to round corners inside block, like subtracting circle?

Like here: http://malsup.com/jquery/corner/

Curl settings

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "inside block" and "subtracting circle". Here is an example using `border-radius` to style a `div` to look like a circle: http://jsfiddle.net/39N9V/

Comment: @showdev: He means he wants the corners to curve inwards, instead of outwards. Think a negative border-radius, only I doubt anything like that exists.

Comment: No there's no such thing in CSS, however if you show us what are you trying to achieve we can find other ways to do this.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha, yes. you are right. But negative border-radius does not work.

Comment: Its not overly browser supported, you could use a PNG background image however to create the effect. Which in my view would be easier and more browser compatible.

Comment: @YotamOmer, I edited question. Sorry for this..

Comment: This might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11033615/inset-border-radius-with-css3 An example: http://jsfiddle.net/39N9V/1/

Comment: @showdev, why not writing this in answer box? Anyway, thanks!

Answer (score 7):

This can be done by adding four circular "gradient" background images on top of the normal background image, each positioned at the appropriate corner. There's an example [on Lea Verou's blog](http://lea.verou.me/2011/03/beveled-corners-negative-border-radius-with-css3-gradients/). From that I've extracted a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EjE7c/1814/); the key code is

```
.round {
    background:
        radial-gradient(circle at 0 100%, rgba(204,0,0,0) 14px, #c00 15px),
        radial-gradient(circle at 100% 100%, rgba(204,0,0,0) 14px, #c00 15px),
        radial-gradient(circle at 100% 0, rgba(204,0,0,0) 14px, #c00 15px),
        radial-gradient(circle at 0 0, rgba(204,0,0,0) 14px, #c00 15px);

    background-position: bottom left, bottom right, top right, top left;
    background-size: 50% 50%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;

    padding: 14px;
}
```

Comment: You beat me to the clock! Just to add a note about upcoming standard W3C `border-corner-shape` http://lea.verou.me/2013/03/preview-border-corner-shape-before-implementations/

Comment: Variant, but I need most cross-browser solution.

Comment: How would that work on inputs?

Comment: @MadaraUchiha the same way it works on every other element... http://jsfiddle.net/EjE7c/1815/

Comment: @Domenic, but looks very strange :D

Comment: Note that this doesn't seem to work in Safari 5.1.9. I assume the culprit is browser compatibility for `radial-gradiant`: http://css-tricks.com/css3-gradients/

Comment: @showdev yes, Safari 5.1.9 still uses nonstandard radial gradient syntax; you need the crappy old WebKit syntax if you want it to work there.

Comment: Can the CSS solution posted by me used as an alternative ?

Comment: 7 years later `border-corner-shape` is now `corner-shape` and in the CSS4 draft with no browser support in sight. So sad.

Answer (score 1):

No, there isn't a way to do it with pure CSS as far as I know. It's not even simple to do it with JavaScript or jQuery.

As far as I know, the jQuery plugin you linked is the one that works best for you, especially since you want a cross-browser solution, which advanced CSS3 isn't there yet, and it is the one you should use.

Comment: Thanks, I just wanted to know if exists any Right Way in doing such things. Know I know some ways doing that with two div's with border-radius and with gradient overlay and with js

Comment: @ArtemE: The right way is Domenic's answer, and the hell with IE.

Comment: See the CSS solution below posted

Answer (score 1):

There is one way to do it with pure CSS:

CSS code:

```
div {
height: 200px;
background: red;
position: relative;
width:200px;
}

div:after {
content: '';
position: absolute;
top: -20px; right: -20px;
border-top: 50px solid white;
border-left: 50px solid white;
width: 0;
background:#fff;
    border-radius:100px;

}
div:before {
content: '';
position: absolute;
top: -20px; left: -20px;
border-top: 50px solid white;
border-left: 50px solid white;
width: 0;
background:#fff;
    border-radius:100px;

}
```

HTML:
`<div></div>`

[Here is an example:](http://jsfiddle.net/MQFNT/)

Comment: Yes, it can be one more solution. Regards