# Is there a way to have a corner rounded on the outside?

Tags: css

*Similar* to [Inset border-radius with CSS3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11033615/inset-border-radius-with-css3) but *different*.

I'd like this kind of rounding:

[image: inner corner rounded on the outside]

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
<div class='flex flex-col justify-end'>
  <p class='bg-gray-800/75 rounded-b-none rounded-lg px-1 mr-auto'>2023</p>
  <h3 class='bg-gray-800/75 rounded-tl-none rounded-lg px-1 mr-auto'>Freelance</h3>
</div>
```

Constrains: I'm okay to use JS, but I would prefer a pure CSS solution, if it exists.

Comment: Depends on your HTML. Please add your HTML and any constraints you have to the question. See [mcve] for more info. Also, can you use JavaScript, or are you limited to CSS and HTML only?

Comment: Typically this will be done with SVG or a mask and will require additional elements.

Comment: It's *different*... How?

Comment: @HereticMonkey Because in the question I linked, the rounded corner is *subtracted* from the shape whereas my question was about *adding* a rounded shape to the initial shape

Comment: That should be in the question not a comment.  As it is, there is nothing in the question that says anything about adding anything.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like `clip-path` is the easiest way to do this:

```css
div {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: red;
    clip-path: path(
        "M 0,0 L 0,200 L 200,200 L 200,100 L 120,100 S 95,100 100,80 L 100,0 L 0,0"
    );
}
```

```html
<div>
    <p>Hi there</p>
    <p>this is a test</p>
</div>
```

I'm horrible with SVG, but if I get some time, maybe I'll see if I can get the shape a little closer haha.

Anyways I think this demo still shows it's possible. Biggest issue is that it isn't based on the height of your elements so you will have to keep those in sync manually but I think it could work

Comment: Yes for my use case, keeping the sizing of an svg in sync manually is not worth the effect obtained, but thank you anyway!

Comment: You could of course use JavaScript to dynamically generate the clip path size if that is worth it