# CSS nav bar with reverse rounded corners

Tags: css, navigation

[image: required nav bar]

Can i make this type of nav bar using css only not using image at all .

this is my current result

[image: current nav bar]

```
 .tabrow:before {
    position: absolute;
    content: " ";
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}
.tabrow li:after {
    right: -6px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 6px;
    border-width: 0 0 1px 1px;
    box-shadow: -2px 2px 0 #D1D1D1;
}
.tabrow li.selected:before {
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 0 #FFF;
}
.tabrow li.selected:after {
    box-shadow: -2px 2px 0 #FFF;
}
```

here is a fiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/vup9jg5k/)

i am having problem with first and last child of li.

Comment: Please provide the code of what you have tried so far and put it within your question. A demo (even when it's broken) will also help to answer your question.

Comment: now i have provided a sample code now can you help @secelite

Comment: Please check this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8929173/css3-menu-with-inverse-rounded-corners/8931791#8931791. It seems exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: thnx @secelite exactly what i needed :D
can you post your answer so i can mark that as a correct answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for are inverse rounded corners. There is alreay a solution on SO.

You can view it here: [css3 menu with inverse rounded corners](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8929173/css3-menu-with-inverse-rounded-corners/8931791#8931791).

For sure, you have to adept it to your code.